# Why does this implementation of the C++ 'new' operator work?

Tags: c++, memory, malloc, avr, libc

I've found out that the C++ compiler for AVR uCs doesn't support the `new` and `delete` operators, but also that there is a quick fix:

```
void * operator new(size_t size) 
{ 
  return malloc(size); 
} 

void operator delete(void * ptr) 
{ 
  free(ptr); 
}
```

I'm assuming that it would now be possible to call `new ClassName(args);`.

However, I am not really sure how this works. For example, what actually returns a `size_t` here? I thought that constructors don't return anything...

Could it be that `new` is now supposed to be used differently (in conjunction with `sizeof()`)?

Comment: don't confuse new and operator new. Yes it's slightly tricky. operator new which you are overloading just allocates memory. You can use malloc or a special memory pool and you can decorate it too to help with memory leak detection and invalid deletes etc.

Comment: Does this mean that it doesn't actually instantiate the class at all or what? I'm a bit confused by what you said.

Comment: always keep in mind that the operator new (that you can overload) and the new expression (that you normally use to create new objects in code) are two different things.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, OK, I didn't know that. Hopefully the compiler supports the new expression.

Comment: @Yannbane: If it does not, it is not a C++ compiler.

Comment: In http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=59453&start=all&postdays=0&postorder=asc you can found the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`new T(args);` is roughly equivalent to the following.

```
void* storage = operator new(sizeof(T)); // obtain raw storage
call_constructor<T>(storage, args); // make an object in it
```

(Here `call_constructor` is supposed to call the constructor<sup>†</sup> of `T` making `storage` be the `this` pointer within that constructor.)

The `operator new` part obtains the requested amount of raw storage, and the constructor call is the one that actually makes an object, by invoking the constructor.

The code in the question only replaces the `operator new` part, i.e. the retrieval of storage. Both the `sizeof` part and the constructor invocation are done automatically by the compiler when you use `new T(args)`.

---

† The language has a way to express this direct constructor invocation called "placement `new`", but I omitted it for clarity.

Comment: I thought the `operator` part was part of the operator defining syntax... So I need to add that `call_constructor` part somewhere?

Comment: @Yannbane No, that the compiler knows how to do. I made the answer more explicit on that point.

Comment: OK, I just learned that the "new expression" and "operator new" are two different things, so I figured that part out. Thanks!

Comment: For call_constructor you could write new(storage) T(args); of course

Comment: @CashCow yeah, that's what I mention in the footnote, but I thought adding another syntax involved `new` into the mix would make the explanation more confusing. :(

Answer (score 0):

From the compiler name (uC), I presume it's for embedded controller.  This would make sense as you rarely require dynamic memory management with embedded devices, but might benefit from 'C with classes'.  Hopefully it supports 'placement new' so you can actually use C++.

If your compiler doesn't support new & delete, it's not really much of a a C++ compiler is it!

I think the keyword 'new' effectively gets converted to:

```
Object* pointer = (Object *)new(sizeof Object);
pointer->Object_Constructor(args);
```